# how to set a memory breakpoint in windbg kernel mode?

Tags: debugging, memory, reverse-engineering, windbg, breakpoints

I would like to set a memory breakpoints on access in windbg in the kernel mode debugger

I want the debugger breaks everytime a specific module in usermode is hit with the kernel debugger.

but I've read somewhere its impossible to set it, in order to make a memory breakpoints I have to write a plugin to make it

I tried to use SDbgExt plugin with the !vprotect command, but it fails to set memory bp

If I have to write a plugin to allow memory bp in kernel mode It has to be a driver?

I've read some chapters in windows internals book, but it doesn't help me at all.

I couldn't find too much info how to start deal with it

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints on user mode addresses from kernel mode. The only thing you should take care is to switch to the right process with ".process /i " command

Comment: The problem isnt to set the breakpoint itself, the problem is to set memory breakpoint on access in all the region from the kernel mode
there isnt command to do it

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one-off breakpoint -- that is, you are content with process being destroyed by debugging -- zero out the entire module using e command (edit memory). Set the whole thing to cc (which is int 3 as far as I remember)... zeros will do as well. You will break as soon as you touch any of the module's code.

Next step, remember where you were (relative to the module) and set a proper breakpoint.

Hope that helps.

(editing) Do you have full symbols? If you do, did you try bm module!*

Comment: I need a memory breakpoint on access, int 3(0xcc) wont help me
because it works in another way, I dont know where I want to break in the module I want to know from where it called and the only way to do it is set mem bp on access in all the region for example I have an address 
start at 6fd00000 and address end at 6ff00000.
I would like to set between those two range mem bp on access so when it hits the place I get control and see from where it happened

I dont have symbols for the app

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to set a "breakpoint on access" but instead of specifying an address you want to specify a range? I have never seen it done in windbg. The BA breakpoints uses HW debug registers instead of inserting INTs like SW breakpoints so this is definitely HW platform specific. 
I have done this on an ARM chipset once using a HW debugger. ETM on ARM allows you to set triggers on address ranges.